# CSS: vertical scrollbar disappears when browser is resized (narrowed)

Tags: javascript, css

What causes this to happen? I would expect the vertical scrollbar to appear no matter how narrow the browser window is. The content in the grid is dynamic, but this issue seems to have nothing to do with the no of rows in the grid. The scrollbar appears when the browser window is a certain size and remains as the window is widened, but disappears when the window is narrowed. The height is dynamic and set by the element as a style attribute via JavaScript.

```html
<div id="mycontainer" class="mydiv" style="height: 142px;"></div>
<style>
    .mydiv {    
        background-color: white;     
        border-color: #d8d8d8;    
        border-style: solid;    
        border-width: 0 1px 1px;    
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%    
        margin: 0;    
        overflow-y: auto;    
        padding: 0;    
        position: relative;    
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Without seeing your javascript I can't say for sure. But in a JSFiddle, the border-width-property adds 1px to the bottom of the div, which makes it 100% + 1px high. This will most definitely trigger a scollbar, if overflow is set to auto. You may get around this by setting box-sizing to border-box.

This should work in any browser: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing

Comment: It's not possible to reproduce your issue with only the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the situation is you are using overflow-y, that is preventing the div from showing the scrollbar, that and the fact you have no content inside the div, maybe you could share a plnkr with the div and the content?

Comment: `overflow-y: auto` means: only show vertical scrollbar if needed

Comment: Precisely, and right now it is *not* needed because there's no content, that's why I'm recommending creating a Plnkr.

Comment: But i am varying the width of the browser window, not the height. So the no of rows in the grid stays constant, and i need the vertical scrollbar to see all the rows, even if the browser is narrowed or widened.

Comment: You could try with:
width: 100%;

Comment: Also you are overriding rules by placing inline styles on the div, you declare the property *height* twice.

Comment: I tried adding width: 100%;  but it didn't help. Making the browser less wide causes the vertical scrollbar to disappear at some point.